# Issues with EC2 Load balancer, SNI, multiple SSL domains on the same server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

i am having issues setting up an EC2 load balancer, on a instance, that has multiple domains protected by SSL.

Is it possible to make the load balancer pass the HTTPS request as is, and get it decrypted at the server level? If so, how do i set that up?

I have a standard LAMP setup on a EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Elastic Load Balancer, configure a TCP listener that listens on port 443 and forwards to port 443 on the instances. This will allow your EC2 instances to perform the SSL termination.

Note that you won't be able to use Sticky Sessions in this configuration.